# CPU number of cores seems not correct

Tags: cpu

[image]

As the image shows number of processors are 4.

But intel i5-4210U has only 2 cores as shown below. (Intel's own specs.)

[image]

So, if i5-4210U has only 2 cores than what is "4" indicating in the 1st pic?

`lscpu` gives this result:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 69
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               989.531
BogoMIPS:              4788.74
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Comment: Because it has [Hyperthreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), which means that the CPU presents four cores to the OS, instead of only the two physical ones, in order to improve performance. ("_# of threads_" from the spec sheet is what the CPU info in Ubuntu is showing you)

Comment: The other way of finding this out is to do `lscpu` and look at `CPU(s)`, `Thread(s) per core` and `Core(s) per socket` and `Socket(s)`.

Comment: @edwinksl , added result of lscpu.

Comment: So you have 4 "CPUs" aka logical cores, 2 threads per physical core (this is the hyperthreading part), 2 physical cores per socket and 1 socket. 4 = 2*2*1.

Comment: you didn't hear hyperthreading which exists since pentium 4?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc , I heard the name 'hyperthreading' but I never searched for it before.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your CPU has only 2 cores, but supports **4 concurrent threads**.

This is achieved by [Intel's Hyper-Threading technology](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/hyper-threading/hyper-threading-technology.html) that allows to run two separate threads in parallel at the same time on one single core.

So 2 cores x 2 threads per core means 4 threads per CPU.

Comment: I know little bit about threads so I am curious how this can be achieved at hardware level? I mean 2 threads per CPU?

Comment: I can't really start explaining the whole concept behind hyper threading here, this would blow up the answer. Instead I would like to suggest you to read the corresponding [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) or feed your favourite search engine with "hyperthreading".

Comment: In short, we can say that a hyperthreading-capable core has some elements (architectural state i.e. the registers etc) duplicated while others (execution engine, cache) are shared.

Comment: @foxtrot9 basically, a single thread of execution usually doesn't use anywhere near 100% of a CPU core — the CPU spends time waiting for data to load from memory, and any given instruction doesn't use all of the little circuits (execution units) in the core that do various things. HT lets two threads of execution share the core, so one can run while the other is waiting, or they both can run if they use disjoint sets of execution units. But because the two threads have to share resources, sometimes one stops the other from running, so it's not as fast as 2 whole cores.

Comment: @hobbs Detailed but simple explanation, great! Thanks for this informative comment :)

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the image you provided from Intel, the number of Threads is `4`.

So I would say that Ubuntu is showing the number of Threads and not of the Cores

Answer (score 0):

In i5-4210 processor of Intel there are 2 physical cores which are further split into 2 logical cores; these logical cores are achieved by Intel's hyper threading technology. Thus making it a total of 4 cores as shown in the pic. This info is also given in the other pic.

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting your answer, what you've said is true.

Comment: People are dumb then, I don't mind.

Comment: Just to back up this answer, Wikipedia says: "For each processor core that is physically present, the operating system addresses two virtual (logical) cores."

Comment: Thnx @lightswitchr

Comment: I think people are downvoting because you said that there are two physical cores and two logical cores. That's not true, each physical core is split into two logical cores, so there are four logical cores (two running on each physical core).

Comment: It may be the reason, sorry for my mistake guys.

Comment: @Moksh Your assertion is only partially correct. The number of physical cores in Intel i5 processors can vary and may be **either** 2 or 4. For example, my i5-6600K, a desktop CPU, has 4 physical and 4 threads (no hyper threading). The i5-4210 is part of Intel's "Mobile Processor" line where (apparently) the number of physical cores is 2.

Comment: @irrational you're right but I gave the answer as per i5-4210 as the person who asked the question had that version of processor. Thanks though.

Comment: @irrational as per my knowledge both support hyperthreading.

Comment: @Moksh You may have intended your answer to refer only to the i5-4210, but you begin by stating _"In i5 processor of Intel there are 2 physical cores"_. This statement, as written, is not correct. Just sayin' ... And, no, the i5's with 4 physical cores do **not** support hyper-threading.