# Getting information about CPU

Tags: cpu, cpuinfo

I am new to the world of Linux and Ubuntu. I want say get maximum information about CPU. (cpufreq , no. of cores, no. of threads per core, instruction set, size of caches, instruction set, virtualization etc.)

I would prefer a method which works on all Linux distributions over Ubuntu specific approaches.

`lscpu` seems to give only few info, I especially miss the model name here:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 69
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               989.531
BogoMIPS:              4788.74
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Running `sudo lscpu` returns same.

Comment: You can do `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: Err… But, everything you listed is being shown by `lscpu`. So what information do you need additionally?

Comment: @Hi-Angel , it doesn't show CPU chip info i.e.: i7 or i5 and model number.

Comment: @foxtrot9 But `lscpu` on my machine does show the model number. I am not sure why yours doesn't.

Comment: @foxtrot9 what does show `lscpu | grep "Model name"` ?

Comment: I have already added result of lscpu at this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/806520/cpu-number-of-cores-seems-not-correct).

Comment: @Hi-Angel , nothings shows up for `lscpu | grep "Model name"` .

Comment: You could also try `sudo lshw -c cpu`

Comment: None of these command says anything about maximum possible frequency for that particular cpu.

Comment: @foxtrot9 does anything change if you run the command with elevated privileges, i.e. `sudo lscpu | grep "Model name"`

Comment: @Hi-Angel , I tried that before I responded to you about same. Nothing extra for `sudo lscpu | grep "Model name"`

Comment: Oh, wow, I figured out what's the problem with `lscpu`. Right now I have a terminal chrooted into Archlinux, and I was running `lscpu` there, and I saw both model number and frequencies *(current, max, min)*. But I just ran the same command in host Ubuntu 14.04, and I doesn't see those either. So, turns out the problem is that you have `util-linux` package too old. On the chrooted system, where I see that, I have `2.28-1` version.

Comment: Well mine one returns everything about my cpu even the model name . not sure whats happening with you.I am in arch linux though. So there might be some problem with your installation or your pc is unable to correctly identify your processor.

Comment: @KuntalMajumder , you have new package as mentioned by Hi-Angel in above comment.

Comment: oops! I havent noticed that , there were a few more comments, sorry!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can check the model no by executing

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | uniq
```

Output:

```
 model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz
```

To Count number of CPUs:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor
```

**Output** :

```
2
```

To check the number of cores !

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id'
core id         : 0
core id         : 1

$hardinfo | less


$nproc  / prints out the number of processing units
```

For **Windows Users** Use CPU-Z [here](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html)

For more info described for both windows and linux [here](http://renderwebsolutions.com/ubuntu-centos-debian-fedora/to-find-the-number-of-cpu-cores-and-virtual-cores/).